# Force link to open in same browser instead of app

Tags: html

Is there a way to format a URL to open in the browser that the URL was opened from, rather than a corresponding app the user may have installed? For example, if a user taps on a link to a public DropBox folder within Safari iOS and the user already has DropBox installed on their phone, the DropBox app will open and direct them to the folder, instead of Safari doing this. Long-tapping on the link in Safari and tapping Open in Background is an insufficient workaround as I want the link to open in the browser by default.